# Where is the source xml of TFS build notification mail template?

Tags: tfs

TFS build mail template is located on %PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Application Tier\TFSJobAgent\Transforms, example:BuildCompletedEvent.xsl

But, can someone tell me where is the source xml which is used to generate the notification mail?

Answer (score 2):

The templates to build the notification emails are literally one folder down in the **1033** folder.

Your final path would look like: **%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Application Tier\TFSJobAgent\Transforms\1033**.

Here's a blog post on adding a hyperlink to the *WorkItemChangedEvent.xsl* template: http://blog.nwcadence.com/add-a-hyperlink-to-work-item-changed-alert-email/

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question.  The question is asking about what the source of the XML that is passed to the XSL is.